# KafkaListener annotation at class level with errorhandler property ignored

Tags: spring-kafka

When using the kafkalistener annotation at class level and the provided errorhandler property is ignored. When method is annotated with kafkalistner and the provided errorhandler is working. Is it expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really bug. The piece of code:

```
    String errorHandlerBeanName = resolveExpressionAsString(kafkaListener.errorHandler(), "errorHandler");
    if (StringUtils.hasText(errorHandlerBeanName)) {
        endpoint.setErrorHandler(this.beanFactory.getBean(errorHandlerBeanName, KafkaListenerErrorHandler.class));
    }
```

Is missed in the:

```
private void processMultiMethodListeners(Collection<KafkaListener> classLevelListeners, List<Method> multiMethods,
        Object bean, String beanName) {
```

Unfortunately I don't see a simple way to workaround this. Please, consider to have a single `@KafkaListener` method with an `Object` as payload and manual type routing in that method to others.

Feel free to raise a GitHub issue on the matter!

Comment: Please, see my corrected answer. Unfortunately multi `@KafkaListener` s is not going to be as a solution, since all of them are going to compete for records in the topic.

Comment: Here is the fix: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/904

Comment: minor observation : There is a typo in spring kafka documentation: It says --- Alternatively, you can configure a failedDeserializationFunction which is a BiConsumer<byte[], headers, T> -- it should be BiFunction

Comment: Nice! Feel free to PR the fix! Btw if my answer is OK with you, consider to accept it. That’s how SO works